# Automation for birthday adding contacts the day after instead the exact day

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, date, automation

we're experiencing some issues with a birthday automation query.

Our query runs everyday and should filter contacts from 2 DE (contacts that are celebrating their birthday on that day) and put it in a DE used for a journey.

The problem is that the contacts are being pushed into the final DE the day AFTER their birthday. the quesry runs everyday without showing any error.

We believe this could be related to the "getdate" function, there our query:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM 
(SELECT a1.*,
   CASE
      WHEN
         DAY(a1.[Birth date]) = 29 AND MONTH(a1.[Birth date]) = 2 
      THEN
         CASE
            WHEN
               YEAR(getdate()) % 400 = 0 
            THEN
               DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), 02, 29) 
            ELSE
               DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), 03, 01) 
         END
      ELSE
         DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR (getdate()), MONTH(a1.[Birth date]), DAY(a1.[Birth date])) 
   END
   AS DT_NASC_GGMM 
FROM
   [DE1] a1) AS a
 
LEFT JOIN [DE2] b
ON a.[unique id] = b.[unique id]
LEFT JOIN [DE3] c
ON a.[unique id] = c.[unique id]
WHERE
   a.[E-mail] is not null
   AND DAY(a.[DT_NASC_GGMM]) = DAY(GETDATE()) 
   AND MONTH(a.[DT_NASC_GGMM]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
   AND b.[E-mail] is not null
```

Do you have any hint about what could be causing this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are the birthdays correct in the source data? I have seen problems that birthdays were not on the proper day because of timezone issues.

Comment: What's the data type of `DE1.[Birth Date]`?

Comment: `GetDate()` will always return US Central Time with no DST.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Your help has been precious! At the end, after testing and reviewing your suggestions, it appeared to be a timezone problem. Just Post-poning the running time of the automation, the query started to work properly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just checking the current date and the birth date, the leap year case statement seems like an unnecessary complexity.

Converting the `datetime` data types to `date` will strip the time.

You can also adjust the time zone using the `at time zone 'WHATEVER TIME ZONE HERE'`.  [Here's the list](https://bornsql.ca/blog/dates-and-times-in-sql-server-at-time-zone/) of those I use).

```sql
CREATE TABLE DE1(
     birthDate datetime
)
;
INSERT INTO DE1 
  (birthDate)
VALUES
  ('2023-10-25')
;
 
select
  a.birthDate_orig
, a.birthDate
, day(a.birthDate) as birthDate_Day
, month(a.birthDate) as birthDate_Month
, a.today
, day(a.today) as today_day
, month(a.today) as today_month
from (
   select
   a1.birthdate as birthdate_orig
   , convert(date, a1.birthdate) as birthDate
   , convert(date, getDate() at time zone 'US Eastern Standard Time')   as today
  from DE1 as a1
) as a
where 1=1 
/*
AND day(a.birthDate) = day(a.today) 
AND month(a.birthDate) = month(a.today)
*/
```

| birthDate_orig | birthDate | birthDate_Day | birthDate_Month | today | today_day | today_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-25 00:00:00.000 | 2023-10-25 | 25 | 10 | 2023-10-25 | 25 | 10 |

**Try it yourself**: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6eVoQib9)

I reproduced your query [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/UQZRNDgV).  I made `today` a column value so you can simulate the calculations.

Once you're satisfied with the testing in the dbfiddle, you can make the corresponding changes in your Query Activity.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Your help has been precious! At the end, after testing and reviewing your suggestions, it appeared to be a timezone problem. Just Post-poning the running time of the automation, the query started to work properly! Thanks!